# How to calculate the percentage between two numbers?

Tags: percentages

Assiming the firt is always the bigger one and the second is the smallest

how to calculate the percentage between them, ex:

100, 25 = 25%

thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I don't understand the question. Do you mean that 25 is 25% of 100 in your example?

Comment: What do you mean by "the percentage between them?"  $\dfrac{25}{100} = 25\%$, but we don't say "there is 25% between 25 and 100."

Comment: Divide and you'll conquer

Comment: When you are quantifying the *decrease*, use the larger value as a base (denominator), and when the *increase* is being quantified, use the smaller value as base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$25\%$ means $\frac{25}{100}$, so if

$$
100,25 \rightarrow \frac{25}{100} \rightarrow 25\%
$$
 we have also
$$
50,25 \rightarrow \frac{25}{50}=\frac{50}{100} \rightarrow 50\%
$$